# SQLExecDirect failed but SQLGetDiagRec has no data

Tags: error-handling, odbc

I'm trying to setup some useful error handling in a program that used ODBC. According to documentation if SQLExecDirect returns SQL_ERROR I should be able to call SQLGetDiagRec to get SQL_STATE and possibly some messages, but in my tests when I call SQLGetDiagRec right after getting an error from SQLExecDirect I get SQL_NO_DATA returned and no information.

Code:

```
result = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, <SQL Statement>, SQL_NTS);

if(result == SQL_ERROR)
{
    SQLSMALLINT msg_len = 0;
    SQLCHAR sql_state[6], message[256];
    SQLINTEGER native_error = 0;

    result = SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc, 1, sql_state, &native_error, message, countof(message), &msg_len);

    // Here 'result' is SQL_NO_DATA

    ....
}
```

It works in other cases, just not for SQLExecDirect for some reason. I'm also aware that one should cycle through the SQLGetDiagRec results, but if the very first one returns SQL_NO_DATA, according to documentation it means that there are no further ones.

The specific error that I was testing it with was requesting a non-existent table.

Is there anything else that I need to do in order obtain at least an error code, or does the diagnostic not work for errors that result from incorrect SQL requests?

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out for this?  I'm seeing the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

When you call SQLGetDiagRec, pass SQL_HANDLE_STMT and your statement handle (hstmt in your example).  That should return errors associated with that specific statement.